# How to deploy a contract using hardhat and ethersjs v6

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, hardhat-deploy

[image]

This is the deploy script that I have written still it is not running.

Answer (score 4):

Try two things:

1. Comment out the require statement.
2. Directly use `deployContract` function.

   ```
   const mynft= await ethers.deployContract("MyNFT");
     await wallet.waitForDeployment();
   ```

Also notice in the console log statement that `mynft.address` should be `mynft.target`

Comment: It is working , thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Cool, mark this as an answer :)

Comment: @AnjishnuGanguly check the tick to let the community know that this query has been solved.